Отправка письма на почту из терминала линукс
Пытаюсь отправить письмо через mailutils из терминала линукс
installer@astra172se:~$ mail -s "Test email" receiver1@mail.ru
Cc: 
Hi Silver
Your code is
12345
Bye
installer@astra172se:~$ 

Никаких ошибок, все вроде бы выполняется (хотя сам терминал после "отправки письма" секунд 10 виснет и по итогу никакого письма не приходит).
Делал по гайду: https://rus-linux.net/MyLDP/consol/mails.html

на mail.ru разрешено программам подключаться?

Попробуйте использовать консольного клиента, я в свое время использовал mutt т.к. он умеет делать attach.
